# Changing URL from /%postname%/%post_id to /%category%/%postname%/%post_id%

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I want to add categories to my URL structure. I'm sure this has been covered and I found many resources online to create the redirect code in .htaccess, but when I enter the code it doesn't work. Running an Apache server.

Essentially, I want to go from

```
https://example.com/this-is-a-post/1111
```

to

```
https://example.com/posts-category/this-is-a-post/1111
```

I added the following to my .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/(\d+)/$ https://example.com/$1
```

But I still get 404s when accessing links from outside sources (Google, Reddit etc)

Comment: Why not just use a [custom structure](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#choosing-your-permalink-structure) - on the Permalink Settings page, just enter `/%category%/%postname%/%post_id%/` in the Custom Structure box.

Comment: "I found many resources online to create the redirect code in .htaccess" - You can't do that sort of redirect in `.htaccess` - where are you expected to get the `posts-category` part from? The above directive (apart from using the wrong directive with WordPress) would redirect to `/this-is-a-post` - which does not seem to be what you require. But the redirect is not necessary to get this to work anyway, only to preserve SEO.

Comment: We have over 2,000 articles and 55,000 backlinks to these articles. If I just change the permalinks I will have over 50k 404s which will break the site.

Comment: Is there no way of adding /category/ without doing manual redirects?

Comment: @cjmi, there is - use custom PHP/WordPress code like in my answer, in addition to changing the permalinks. I hope the answer helps and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Btw, when responding to someone's comment, you should tag that person so that he/she would be notified of your responses. Tag like this: @cjmi

Answer (score 2):

So first, I'm quoting [@MrWhite's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/8259/mrwhite) comment:

> You can't do that sort of redirect in `.htaccess` - where are you
>   expected to get the `posts-category` part from?

And he's right — you shouldn't use the `.htaccess`.

> We have over 2,000 articles and 55,000 backlinks to these articles. If
>   I just change the permalinks I will have over 50k 404s which will
>   break the site.

You should just change the permalink structure and use custom code to redirect old URLs to the new ones.

**Step 1: Change the permalink structure.**

Just go to the Permalink Settings page and in the Custom Structure box, enter this:

```
/%category%/%postname%/%post_id%/
```

**Step 2: Add custom PHP/WordPress code to redirect old URLs to new ones.**

This is an example (tried and tested working) using the [`parse_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) hook: (this would go in your theme `functions.php` file) (and the code uses these two WordPress functions: [`get_post_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/) and [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/))

```php
add_action( 'parse_request', 'maybe_redirect_old_permalinks' );
function maybe_redirect_old_permalinks( $wp ) {
    if ( preg_match( '#^([^/]+)/(\d+)$#', $wp->request, $matches ) ) {
        list ( $path, $slug, $id ) = $matches;
        // Redirect to the new permalink, if the slug and ID match.
        if ( $slug === get_post_field( 'post_name', $id ) ) {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $id ), 301 );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

This approach also means that both `example.com/<post slug>/<post ID>` and `example.com/<post category>/<post slug>/<post ID>` would work. But on the page (post content, widgets, etc.), post permalinks would only be in the later format.