# How to change URL from /%postname%/ to custom-name/%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I am trying to change our news media website permalink structure to more explanatory and useful link for our readers. We started wrong using just the Post name structure as we thought it would be best.

```
Current: https://our-website.com/post-name
```

We want to change it to

```
This: https://our-website.com/abc/2021/08/30/post-name
```

Initially I Tried looking for a solution with .htaccess but checking this - [Changing URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/349645/changing-url-from-postname-post-id-to-category-postname-post-id) I understood that having php would be our solution. I am not sure how to implement the solution provided by Sally Cj to my case. Can someone please give some guides or let me know of a solution. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to set up the custom permalink structure via settings => permalinks? They have plenty of options there.

Comment: I will change it there but I want the ranked pages to be just redirected to the new url. Otherwise everything will be pointed to a 404 page.